# How to list waiting validators?

Tags: validator, grandpa, babe, session

We can list the active set with `session::validators()` and/or `babe::authorities()`

How to list *waiting* validators though?

[image: active and waiting validators]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Staking::validators()` to get all validators.

Then:

```rs
let all = Staking::validators();
let active = Session::validators();
let waiting = all.difference(active);
```

Comment: Failing at the above bc `staking::validators(who)` requires me knowing that `who` mapping key. I'm trying to do this with `@polkadot/api`.

Comment: There should be a method to iterate this map.

Comment: https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/1737#issuecomment-577047986

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got it. To get all validators: `await api.query.staking.validators.entries().then(r => r.map(v => v[0].toHuman()[0]))`